# Consolidate files with same name and sequentially number them

Tags: bash

I am working on a Linux Cluster using Bash Commands

I have directories that are numbered 1 through 100 that each contain a file called "FILE1".

How can I consolidate these "FILE1" files into a single directory?

This is what i have tried so far

```
find ./*/ -iname "FILE1" -exec ln -t ./ConsolidatedFILEs/ {} +
```

It would work apart from all of the "FILE1" files having the same name.  This problem results in the following error message.

```
ln: failed to create hard link './2/FILE1': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link './3/FILE1': File exists
ln: failed to create hard link './4/FILE1': File exists
```

Is there an easy way to sequentially number the files to avoid this problem?  I failed to find a solution that was sufficiently easy to understand and implement.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would simply move files, and rename them sequentially.

```
for i in {1..100}; do mv $i/FILE_1 ConsolidatedFILES/FILE_1_$i; done
```

But you mentioned you might have gaps in the numbering, as well as a directory prefix of "IHC_", so here are some additions.

```
for i in {1..100}; do if [ -e "IHC_$i/FILE_1" ]; then mv IHC_$i/FILE_1 ConsolidatedFILES/FILE_1_$i; fi; done
```

Of course, you can replace `mv` with `ln`, if you want a link instead.  And replace `100` with whatever upper limit you expect.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions to adapt this answer for directories named with the convention: IHC_108, IHC_200, IHC_346.  Instead of the directories 1 to 100 described in the question?

Comment: Hi @Paul, I've updated it for the directory format, and possible gaps.